# Mouse events and switch

Tags: macos, mouseevent

I'm very very new to Cocoa and I'm looking for a way to execute an applescript when the mouse is dragged, at a global level. I need this app to be running all the time and it has no interface really, just running in background and intercept mouse event in certain conditions.

So far, with this bit of code I can get close to what I want but the applescript will be executed countless times instead of just once.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDraggedMask handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

     if (NSLeftMouseDragged) //with more conditions than that
         NSAppleScript *run = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"MyScriptHere"];
         [run executeAndReturnError:nil];
         }
     ];
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't look like either of the approaches in the documentation of [Handling Mouse Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html)

Comment: It's true but it acts like it (in a sense that it runs my script multiple times). Do you have any idea of how I can get my code to run once when mousedragged is true?